# Ionic 3 div hide show not working correctly

Tags: typescript, ionic3

I tried to **ionic 3**   div `show` `hide` but its not working? any issue for this my solution?

**.html**

```
   <div>
        <ion-item (click)="alive">Show</ion-item>
          <div class="textboxs" padding *ngIf="alive">
view
          </div>
```

**.ts**

```
   alive() {
  this.alive = true;
}
```

Comment: where is the logic?

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib Hi, i updated my question and i added `.ts` part

Comment: Check my Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**.html**

```
   <div>
          <ion-item (click)="yourFunction()">Show</ion-item>
          <div class="textboxs" padding *ngIf="alive">
                view
          </div>
    </div>
```

**.ts**

```
alive:boolean = true;  //by default false will hide the div.

    yourFunction(){
      this.alive = !this.alive;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to set the (click) attribute to a function in your HTML

```
<ion-item (click)="alive()">Show</ion-item>
```

Should do the trick